# Merge Website Article Likes and Facebook Post Likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

So I have an online publication with a like button for each article page, e.g. http://mafysh.com/%D9%A1%D9%A2-%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B7%D9%82%D8%A9-%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AD%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D9%85%D9%87%D9%85%D8%B4%D8%A9-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B1-%D9%85%D8%AA%D8%B9%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%B4-%D8%B9%D9%86%D9%87/

My problem is it looks like that the article post on my Facebook Fanpage is not merged with that one on the website, e.g. on https://www.facebook.com/mafysh you will find the same first post with half the number of shares, though it links with the same url, on the website its 25 shares, and on the post it's 12 post.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "merging" doesn't work like you imagine. Although the likes, shares and comments from the link on the FB page indeed sum up to the total number of likes/shares of your on-site button, but it doesn't work the other way - if user clicked the share button on your website it will not increment the numbers on your fanpage.

In the moment you asked this questions your numbers might be the following: 10 likes + 0 comments + 12 shares (all on the fanpage) + 3 button shares (on your website) = 25 total "shares".